# Why no camera result?

Tags: android, android-camera, actionbarsherlock

From my `Activity`, which extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` (from the excellent `ActionBarSherlock` library), I make a simple request to get an image from the camera:

```
public void getPhoto() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // .....
}
```

When executed, `onActivityResult()` is called with a `resultCode` of zero (and a matching `requestCode`) when the camera app opens (before taking a picture). If I then take a picture and accept it, `onActivityResult()` is not called.

I'm aware there's a similar bug in `Fragment` in the Support Library, but I'm seeing this issue in `Fragment` and `Activity`.

I've checked and I'm calling the right `startActivityForResult()` (i.e. on `Fragment` or `Activity`), and I've stepped through the code everywhere I can think to. I'm starting to wonder whether the Support Library bug that means `onActivityResult` isn't called in `Fragment` also affects `Activity` when using `ActionBarSherlock`, but I can't believe ABS breaks `onActivityResult()`.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Activity` was specified as `singleInstance` in the manifest. I now know that this is incompatible with `startActivityForResult()` and when the `Activity` was changed to `singleTop`, it all works as expected.